# Using Socket in threads in java on android device when 2 requests required in a execution loop

Tags: java, android, sockets

I need to send two (2) requests do an hardware device requestA and requestB, these have to be executed consecutively in a thread while loop but have encountered a problem that I do not understand yet, I am still very new to java and android, the main hurdle I had is resolved and working very well atm so, on to the next hurdle.

This is my code for the thread..

```
   public void ExecThread(String requestA, String requestB, TextView tv ) {
    TextView te = tv;

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
      {
      String readA = null;
      String readB = null;
      int count = 5;
      byte[] BytesOf = new byte[255];
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        try {
          while(count != 0)
            {
            DataInputStream dis;

              Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out, true);
            output.println(requestA);

            // get response from socket
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dis.readFully(BytesOf, 0, 255);
            dis.close();

            // convert BytesOf to String readA
            readA = new String(BytesOf,0,255);

            socket = new Socket(ip, port);

            output.println(requestB);

            // get response from socket
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); 
        
**dis.readFully(BytesOf, 0, 255); -----> hangs here (I assume waiting for response from device)**

            dis.close();

            readB =  new String(BytesOf, 0, 255);

              if (readA != null && readA.length() >= 250)
                {
                te.setText( String.valueOf(count) + " - " + (CharSequence) readA.substring(4, 16));
                _fields.SetEkmFieldValueStrings(readA, readB);
                }
              socket[0].close();
              count--;
            }
          }
        catch (IOException e)
          {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      };
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
      thread.start();
  }
```

The question I have is, what do I need to do to keep a socket open and get 2 responses from 2 requests, is there a best practice approach for what I am wanting to do?

I accept that I may be doing things wrong so, please point me in  the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The whole point of using threads would be to handle a single connection in each thread.  You have put your code in a thread object, but in that code, you seem to be processing multiple connections.  You also seem to be only starting one thread.  Unless there is an outer method that is calling this method multiple times, I can see no reason to be using a thread here.  I can't tell just what you're trying to do, so I may have it wrong.  I'm just telling you what I see.

Comment: @CryptoFool, the intent is to have a single connection but send 2 requests, it is what I do with my c++ application which I am attempting to, not in full, get my android app to do, the problem, before I tried a second connection for testing, was that I got a exception error when I attempted to send the second request, the exception reported that the Socket was closed but I want the socket to remain open if it is at all possible so I can the task, I need to get the 2 responses from the hardware device in a single connection transaction, is there a way to do this, no problem in my c++ app

Comment: @CryptoFool, the thread will be running polling the device once every second passing the response strings to a synchronized method if java can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, solution to problem was simply to set out = socket.getOutputStream()

My modified code that works for sending 2 requests consecutively and receiving correct response strings from the hardware device is shown

```
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
      {
      String readA = null;
      String readB = null;
      int count = 5;
      byte[] BytesOf = new byte[255];
      String endRequest = "01!\r\n";

      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        try {
          while(count != 0)
            {
            DataInputStream dis;

            Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out, true);
            output.println(requestA);

            // get response from socket
            dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dis.readFully(BytesOf, 0, 255);
            output.flush();
            output.println(endRequest);

            // convert BytesOf to String readA
            readA = new String(BytesOf,0,255);

            out = socket.getOutputStream();  // HERE

            output.flush();
            output.println(requestB);

            // get response from socket
            dis.readFully(BytesOf, 0, 255);
            dis.close();

            readB =  new String(BytesOf, 0, 255);

              if (readA != null && readA.length() >= 250)
                {
                te.setText( String.valueOf(count) + " - " + (CharSequence) readA.substring(4, 16));
                _fields.SetEkmFieldValueStrings(readA, readB);
                }
              socket.close();
              count--;
            }
          }
        catch (IOException e)
          {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
```

Onto the next problem confirming the checksum value of readB is correctly calculated, readA has already been confirmed correct.

Slowly getting to understand java.